# File locked after stream.CopyTo .netCore2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, streaming, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using JSReport in order to generate reports in .netCore2; In the below method the view is returned to the user and report is saved in specified directory;

```
            public IActionResult ImageDownload()
                {

                  HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.PhantomPdf)
                      .Configure((r) => r.Template.Phantom = new Phantom
                      {
                          Format = PhantomFormat.A4,
                          Orientation = PhantomOrientation.Portrait                 
                      }).OnAfterRender( (r) =>
                          {
                             var streamIo = r.Content; // streamIo  is of type System.IO
streamIo.CopyTo(System.IO.File.OpenWrite("C:GeneratedReports\\myReport.pdf"));
                             streamIo.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                 
                          }
                      );

                  var dp = new Classes.DataProvider();
                  var lstnames = dp.GetRegisteredNames();
                  var lst = lstnames.ToArray<string>();
                  return View("Users", lst);
                }
```

Once the view is returned a new browser opens displaying the pdf report. Also the same pdf will be saved in the webserver in the given directory; The problem is that the created report in the directory seems to be locked, I cannot copy it, open it... unless I close the .net solution. Any explanation of what's happening here?

Comment: System.IO.File.OpenWrite() returns a stream that should be closed & disposed, refactor using a using() block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `FileStream` isn't closed when `OnAfterRender` has completed meaning no other app can open/access it. Try changing the code to put a using block around the `File.OpenWrite` call to contain a `using` statement for the `FileStream` e.g.

```
public IActionResult ImageDownload()
{
    HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.PhantomPdf)
        .Configure((r) => r.Template.Phantom = new Phantom
        {
            Format = PhantomFormat.A4,
            Orientation = PhantomOrientation.Portrait                 
        }).OnAfterRender( (r) =>
        {
            var streamIo = r.Content; // streamIo  is of type System.IO
            using(var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("C:GeneratedReports\\myReport.pdf"))
            {
                streamIo.CopyTo(fs);
            }
            streamIo.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                 
        }
    );

    var dp = new Classes.DataProvider();
    var lstnames = dp.GetRegisteredNames();
    var lst = lstnames.ToArray<string>();
    return View("Users", lst);
}
```